After react 18 upgrade page load is logging twice
Recently, I have moved my app from react 17 to react 18. After migration it starts adding the analytics twice when we click on anchor tag.
The anchor tag has hash url and after clicking the page is rendering only one time but analytics showing two page loads.
I am not using strict mode. Any thoughts?

"I am not using strict mode. Any thoughts?" - Yes, this seems a bit dangerous. Readers here can't address issues in code they can't see, so please do [edit] and provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue(s) you describe.

What you described is very similar to react strict mode behavior.
If you're in development mode, it is active by default
This is the relevant part from the documentation:

Strict Mode enables the following development-only behaviors:


Your components will re-render an extra time to find bugs caused by impure rendering.
Your components will re-run Effects an extra time to find bugs caused by missing Effect cleanup.
Your components will re-run refs callbacks an extra time to find bugs caused by missing ref cleanup.
Your components will be checked for usage of deprecated APIs.


I am running in production mode only. Still the same issue.

Can you share more details then? Maybe a piece of your code specially the main app component and the component that is running multiple times?

The issue is due to react-router-dom. After upgraded to version 6 and changed from Switch to Roues, the issue happens. Any solution to keep the latest version?

@AshokYaganti can you share some code? Without seeing the code or being able to reproduce the error, its very difficult to suggest anything useful
